# VB.Net foreach is looping through controls in reverse

Tags: vb.net, foreach

i have this vb.net code where i use foreach to loop through check boxes

but the problem is that it starts from Checkbox 19 to 1 but i want to do this starting from Checkbox1 up to 19

```
Dim i = 0
For Each myControl As CheckBox In Me.Controls
    myControl.Text = Form1.DataGridView1.Columns(i).HeaderText
    myControl.Checked = My.Settings("HC" & i)
i+=1
Next
```

so how can do the above code with normal for loop, i am not sure how to loop through contols using a normal for loop

---

so here is the new working code

```
Option Strict On
Option Infer On



 For i= 1 To 19
        Dim myControl = DirectCast(Me.Controls("CheckBox" + i.ToString()), CheckBox)
        myControl.Text = Form1.DataGridView1.Columns(i).HeaderText
        MsgBox(i)
        myControl.Checked = CBool(My.Settings("HC" & i))
    Next
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a normal `For` loop, you need to manually construct the checkbox name:

```
For i = 1 To 19
    Dim myControl = DirectCast(Me.Controls("checkbox" + i.ToString()), CheckBox)
    ... ' do something with myControl
Next
```

This uses the [ControlCollection indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1865435) to access the control by name and then casts the control to `CheckBox`, so that the correct type can be inferred for the `myControl` variable.

(Obviously, the code sample assumes `Option Strict On` and `Option Infer On`.)

Comment: I was about to write more or less this same answer, but you beat me to it.  Also, the reason I think it may be going through the controls in reverse order is due to them being added to the controls collection of the form/container in that order.

Comment: @Adrian You can check that in the code-behind file generated by the Forms Designer. In general, just don’t rely on the order of the `Controls` collection.

Answer (score 1):

You actually need the integer loop variable, but if you didn't you could use LINQ:

```
 For Each cb In (From c In Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox) Order By CInt(Mid(c.Name, Len("checkbox") + 1)) Select c)
```